# why Each Auxiliary Constructor should call one of the previous defined constructor?

Tags: scala

Well I am new to Scala programming. I struck ed with a question, what is the reason Each Auxiliary Constructor should call one of the previous defined constructor in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

Considering following two situation written in Java:

```
public class Random{

    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Random(int _a, int _b){
        this.a = _a;
        this.b = _b;
    }

    public Random(int _a){
        this(_a, 0);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Random{

    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Random(int _a, int _b){
        this.a = _a;
        this.b = _b;
    }

    public Random(int _a){
        this.a = _a;
        this.b = 0;
    }
}
```

Since both case are valid in Java, however the design of first pattern would be better than second example because of better maintainability

Considering following situation:

`You want to change the name of either attributes`

In first example, you only need to change once, which is the this.a to this.newname, and you don't need to go through all the overloaded constructor to change it.

However in second example, you need to go through all the overloaded constructor.

Because of this design reason, in Scala you must call back the default constructor for the auxilliary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, each class a Primary constructor, this constructor must be called to construct the object.  This is unlike Java which has no concept of primary and auxiliary constructors and all constructors have equal priority.

The primary constructor is special in that fields and parameters declared within it become field on the class usable by other methods in the class called later or even directly accessible if declared public.  If the primary constructor isn't called you can't guarantee that these fields are properly initialized.

So then to enforce that the primary constructor gets called, auxiliary constructors must call this primary constructor, or call another constructor as long as the chain of constructor calls eventually leads to the primary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

we have two types of constructors in Scala.
i) Primary Constructor
ii) Secondary Constructor

We can instantiate the class in scala through primary constructor only, even though we declare any object using auxiliary constructor.

Since the auxiliary constructor is the part of primary constructor(because we define methods, variables ,auxiliary constructors inside primary constructor) and each auxiliary constructor should call the previous defined constructor(auxiliary or primary) and this call finally reaches to primary constructor.

From this we can conclude that primary constructor is the main entry point to instantiate the class and this is the reason each auxiliary constructor must and should call another constructor(predefined auxiliary or primary).